# IOS Swift Tableview controller embedded inside container view is not scrolling to the bottom of the tableview list items

Tags: ios, tableview

I m having issue with tableview trying to be displayed inside container view, the top item is okay, but on scrolling it doesn't scroll to the bottom to show the bottom item, The containerView height is almost half height of the screen, but the tableview controller is full screen one, what i wanted to achieve is to display tableview inside container view, with all smooth scrolling capability, I have succeeded with displaying it , but the issue is with scrolling behaviour, which is not smooth and doesnt scroll to the bottom of it

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help you, I have had same issue before, the problem your having is all about re-arranging the height of tableview to fit into containerview one, so update the height of the tableview view controller into the frame height of container view, like this:

tableViewController.view.frame.size.height = containerView.frame.size.height

you can also change the width to fit it also as your requirement,

this way i solved my issue.